# Vue official website of a confused

Tags: vue.js

[image]

Why this "value" can not be written as "pricevalue" or other, otherwise input will not convert non-numeric values

Comment: Please be specific with the problem of the website.

Comment: Vuejs documentation is fine, you need to read all of it. value prop is required for v-model use on component. You can use pricevalue as a prop if you like and validate it as a number, boolean etc.

If you like to convert data type, you can use this.value as a prop and this.pricevalue as a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

In the `props` element, you are defining the properties your component will attach to. You can call them whatever you want. You need to be clear about a couple of things...

- You define the name [here in camelCase](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case), but when you call the component in the parent markup, use kebab-case.
- `methods` only run when they are called. If you put your formatting on the downstream side (receiving a value and displaying it), everything will be reactive and all your values should display correctly. It will all just work whenever the source value changes. So do your formatting in a computed, like this...

**js**

```
computed: {
    formattedPriceValue(){
        return Number.parseFloat(this.priceValue).toFixed(2)
    }
}
```

You can also just do it inline...

**markup**

```
<input type="number" :value="Number.parseFloat(priceValue).toFixed(2)">
```

The value you want to emit is probably the unformatted output of Number.parseFloat `@change="$emit('price-changed', Number.parseFloat(event.target.value))"`

Then, you will live longer if you do your number formatting with the [Number functions provided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Also, why don't you use the new template (multi-line) strings, delimited by a backtick `. They're much cleaner than the line continuation character you're using.

ps. I love seeing the chinese (?) comments in the code. I've copied and pasted them into my code. I hope there's no swearing. Unicode rocks.